# Magmi all records found but only a few imported

Tags: magento, magmi

I am facing a weird behavior using magmi. as you can see in the image, Magmi sql data-source processes 93 sku as it says in Global Stats but only 1/1 sku is imported into magento as it says in run-time infos.

Additionally, that imported record was loaded perfect into the catalog and displayed at frontend but no other record was loaded.

Any idea why this behavior could be happening?

[image]

my current database table have the following fields:

FieldName => FieldType => Value

- sku = number
- short_description = text
- description = text
- category_ids = text = 45
- type = varchar = simple
- attribute_set = varchar = default
- thumbnail = text
- small_image = text
- image = text
- thumbnail_label = text
- small_image_label = text
- image_label = text
- price = varchar = 11
- cost = varchar = 10
- status = varchar = Active
- name = varchar
- meta_title = text
- meta_description = text
- country_of_manufacture = varchar = US
- weight = varchar = 1
- qty = varchar  = 1
- visibility = varchar = Catalog and Search
- tax_class_id = varchar = 1
- is_in_stock = varchar = 1
- store = varchar = admin
- use_config_manage_stock = integer = 1
- manage_stock = integer = 1

UPDATE: sql file in google drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_L9grdMhRStSEszVnlyWWFsNTQ/edit?usp=sharing

brgds!

Comment: can you share your CSV ?

Comment: is not an csv, im using a query to database with generic sql datasource v1.0.3. I will upload the table in .sql, brgds

Comment: done, I uploaded a table sql file with details.